React keycloack application refresh not working in nested routes
In react I am using keycloak authentication. Problem is when I am refreshing my application, on any root other than the root, I am getting blank screen. In console I am getting

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

when I put 'redirectUri: window.location.href' instead of 'redirectUri: window.location.origin' one level routing started working on page refresh i.e. 'localhost:3000/dashboard'
Now any on any further level routing ie. http://localhost:3000/networktopology/infraview, page refresh is not working and getting blank screen with above given code.

Actually issue was not with keycloak, but the issue was with 'BrowserRouter'. When I used 'HashRouter' instead, the refresh got started working.
